# How to add two or more harvested voltages

Tags: energy-harvesting

We are harvesting power from a variety of sources. Each harvested voltage has its own super capacitor to store. We want all of the super capacitor voltages to contribute to a single Vout, but don't know how to connect their various voltages. How should I approach this?

**update:** When I connect load across output, capacitors discharge. During this time charge moves between top plate of upper capacitor and bottom plate of lower capacitor. How about charge on the inner plates of the capacitors?

Comment: No you don't. You need to get the voltages up to the same usable level and then add the currents.

Answer (score 1):

Commanswer:

> No you don't. You need to get the voltages up to the same usable level and then add the currents. –  Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams

The simplest method is to use diodes, but only the highest individual voltage will appear at the output.

-Determine the highest individual voltage
-Solar is <3V, single-cell, open circuit
-Connect solar in series until you get a similar voltage
-Connect sets-of-solar-in-series in parallel to increase current
-Piezo can be >80VAC, open circuit
-Inductive methods also produce AC

You need to take all of your available input voltages, and determine a single voltage that all of them can supply.

Series-parallel:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9tPLH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Series "micro-supplies" (adapted from Dwayne Reid's answer):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxmGe3.png)</sup>

There is no fixed ground in this schematic; the voltage difference is supplied by whatever source is connected and will find the "best" ground through one or more Schottkys. As long as everything powered by this is referenced to the same "V-", you should be fine. You can pick any V- you want (shown in purple); does V- = 0V or +2.5V? It doesn't matter because V+ will still be 10V (MAX) higher.

Comment: Thank you. When I connect load across output, capacitors discharge. During this time charge moves between top plate of upper capacitor and bottom plate of lower capacitor. How about charge on the inner  plates of the capacitors?

Comment: The total voltage drop across the caps will be Vout. Notice there is no "GND" in the second circuit. If PIEZO is not producing, the solar super-cap will drain through load and return through lower Schottky, back to [the best] "GND". While both are producing, the Schottky's are unused and Vout will appear to be coming from a single 5V, 0.5F cap.

Comment: I have same type of sources and all of them available when they are available. Can I add them in series like in above circuit?

Comment: Without more specific information, probably. This is similar to using 2-"AA" batteries in series to produce the 3V that most logic requires. Your batteries just happen to have a bunch of different voltages and may cut in and out throughout a day.

Comment: Make sure that each micro-supply's cap is rated for at least twice the voltage it outputs. For example, you can stack solar cells in series to add their voltages, and then parallel multiple strands to add their currents. The cap across solar needs to be rated for twice the total solar voltage. Take care with piezos since they can produce harmful-to-a-single-super-cap voltages. Multiple peizo's can be stacked if their motion is synchronized or they will cancel each other out. As long as they are in phase with each other, you can stack them in series or parallel as well.

Comment: Each Schottky will eat up <1V. All colored voltages are ideal; when a power supply turns off, you lose its' Vin plus an additional Schottky drop.

Comment: Hi John,  your design matches with my design exactly. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Jon,  your design matches with my design exactly which I simulated with LTSpice. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are your power sources available at all times?  That is: can you treat each power source as if it was a tiny low-voltage battery that is always charged?

If so, store energy from each source into its' own super capacitor, then put the super capacitors in series.  Note that you will need to ensure that the voltage across any of the super capacitors is never allowed to go negative.

For example, let's assume that you have several low-voltage power sources that come from motion-powered generators.  Each power source puts less than 1 volt DC each.

Accumulate charge from each power source into a super capacitor.  Then simply put all of the super capacitors in series.

The reason I suggest this is because the (little bit of) reading that I've done regarding motion-powered energy harvesting suggests that the resulting voltage from each harvester is quite low.  The only way to make use of that energy is to have some form of very efficient, very low voltage DC-DC converter.

However, if you have multiple independent energy harvesters that are always producing energy, one can simply put those voltage sources in series to get to a higher voltage that is more easily converted to whatever you need.

Note that this works *only* if all of the energy harvesters are all working.

Comment: Could we add a diode across each "micro-supply" to bypass them if they are "off"?

Comment: Can they be in series while they are charging?